# Dice rolling game

Tags: probability, dice

Grallace and Womit are debating who should get to eat the last piece of Wensleydale in the fridge. To decide the issue, they agree to have a "roll-off", using the dice from their old MouseTrap set. The rules of the game are simple: they'll each roll the dice (which is a standard, fair, six-sided dice with faces numbered $1$ to $6$), and whoever obtains the higher number wins. In the event of a tie, they'll both roll again, until there's a winner.

a. What is the probability that Womit wins the game on the first roll? (Give your answer as a fraction in its lowest terms.)

b. What is the probability that Grallace wins the game, but not on the first roll? (Give your answer as a fraction in its lowest terms.)

c. Suppose Grallace rolls first, and gets a '$2$'. At that moment, what is the probability that Womit will win the game? (Give your answer as a fraction in its lowest terms.)

Here is my attempt, have no idea if they are correct so please help.

a. The only way W can win is if he doesn't get a $1$ and there are no draws. So if he gets a 2, then G has to get a 1. The chances of these are 1/6*1/6=1/36

If W gets a 3 then G has to get a 1 or 2 so 1/6*2/6=2/36

W gets 4, then G gets 1 or 2 or 3 so 3/36

W gets 5, then 4/36 and if W gets 6, then 5/36. Add all these up gives 15/36.

b. So the first game has to be a tie which is 1/6 chance. Then since W winning is 15/36, then G winning is 11/36. So 1/6*11/36=11/216.

c. If G gets 2 (which is 1/6 chance), then for G to lose, W has to get 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 (which is 4/6 chance) so 1/6*4/6=2/3

Feel free to chance the tags because I wasn't sure which one to put.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic: Is your professor's last name Kelbert of Suhov?

Comment: nope. this isn't from my uni, its from the internet

Comment: shortcut for a): the probability that $W$ and $G$ throw the same number is $\frac16$. So the probability that there is no draw is $\frac56$. Under that condition both have the same to win so the probability that $W$ wins is half of that (agrees with your $\frac{15}{36}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a)$ Your answer is correct but you can get it easier. Out of the 36 cases, 6 cases are a tie, 15 G wins, 15 W wins (by symmetry). So the answer is $$\frac{15}{36}=\frac{5}{12}.$$

$b)$ The first roll is a tie with probability $\frac{1}{6}$. After that both have the same chance so the answer is $$\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{12}.$$
Another way of seeing this is to compute the probability that G wins in round $i$. We must have a tie in rounds $1,2,\dotsc,i-1$ and G winning in round $i$:
$$\left(\frac16\right)^{i-1}\frac5{12}.$$
Now we sum this up for $2\le i\le \infty$ to get the probability that G wins but not in round 1:
$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty \left(\frac16\right)^{i-1}\frac5{12}=\frac1{12}$$

$c)$ Suppose G gets a $2$. The probability of a tie is then $\frac{1}{6}$ and after that W wins with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. So the probability that W wins and the first round is a tie is $\frac{1}{12}$. The probability that W wins without a tie is $\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$. So in total the probability of W winning is $$\frac{1}{12}+\frac{8}{12}=\frac{9}{12}=\frac{3}{4}.$$
Note that here we are looking for a conditional probability given that G gets a 2. This is already given as something that has happened. So we do not need to consider its probability in our calculations.

Comment: for b. so it is 50% for W win and 50% for G but that eliminates the possibility of a draw doesn't it? from part a. we learned that it is 5/12 for someone to actually win so I don't get how it isn't simply 1/6*5/12

Comment: because it seems like it is assumed that a draw isn't possible in the second roll in part b

Comment: A draw may happen in the second round, but then we'll go to the third round. So at some point, one of them will win and by symmetry the probability of win for each is $\frac12$. The probability $\frac16\times\frac5{12}$ is the probability that G wins in the _second_ round.

Comment: but then why isn't the answer to part a. 1/2?

Comment: The probability that W wins in the _first_ round is $\frac1{12}$. The probability that W wins (in _any_ round or after we know there was a tie like in part b) is $\frac12$. I made an edit that gives another way to do part b.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to a is correct, though the calculation can be simplified: after taking away the 1/6 probability of a draw on the first round you can divide the remaining probability equally between the W and G. And 15/36=5/12.

The answer for b can be deduced from similar considerations. The probability of having more than one round is 1/6, of all games longer than 1 G wins 1/2, which is 1/12. What you solved is for W not to win on the second roll, but that does not mean G wins.

The probability you gave in c is for W to win on the first round, but you neglected the possibility of a tie and W winning later.